# Why are these things giving errors?

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java, and I've been using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpB9u4ItOYU&list=PLfdtiltiRHWFhVOs5BFPgRgN3ac1n-XWY&index=10) as kind of a template. I don't know what I did wrong and the error messages are of much help.

It says I need at least 10 reputation to post images, so I'll have to copypaste it here and tell you which are underlined and the error messages:

```
  import java.util.Random; **Error: the "." after util.**
import java.util.Scanner; **Error: whole line underlined saying "Syntax error on token(s) misplaced construct(s)**

public class game {
private static final String[] enemies = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Random rand = new Random();

String[] enemies = { "troll","rat","imp","goblin" };
int maxEnemyHealth = 80;
int enemyAttackDamage = 20;
int health = 100;
int playerAttackDamage = 30;
int numHealthPots = 3;
// int numStamimaPots = 3 (add stamina potions later on)
int healthPotionHeal = 20;
int healthPotionDropChance = 40; // 40%

boolean running = true;
System.out.println("Welcome, Dungeon Explorer!");

GAME:
while(running) {
System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
}
}
private Scanner rand;
private int maxEnemyHealth;
int enemyHealth = rand.nextInt(maxEnemyHealth);
String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)];
System.out.println("\t#" + enemy + " attacked! #\n"); **Error: Everything after System.out is underlined red with the message: Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead.**

while (enemyHealth > 0); { **Error: while, and the paranthesis after 0 is underlined red with the AnnotatioName message for while and Syntax error, insert ) to complete MethodDelcaration for the paranthesis** 
    System.out.println("HP:" + health);
    System.out.println("\t" + enemy + "'s +" " + HP: + " " + enemyHealth);
    System.out.println("\n\t What do you choose to do?" );
    System.out.println("\t Attack ");
    System.out.println("\t Health Potion");
    System.out.println("\t Run!");

    String input = in.nextLine();
```

help

Comment: `while (enemyHealth > 0);` remove the semicolon as this ends the loop before the `{}` come

Comment: I think you are starting your programming career on the wrong foot. Don't go through the Internet looking for templates to copy. Get a good book and study from the basics. Start with small, 10-line exercises and move up from there. Right now I'm not even sure you are working with an actual Java compiler. Perhaps you are using an IDE for another language.

Comment: under the GAME: label there is code in no method (If I am not lost in brackets :P)

Comment: Adding to @RealSkeptic I think you should start much simpler to get an understanding of the language and what the errors are telling you. We can debug this for you but then what? You're back in 2 minutes with the same problems.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I said it's kind of like a template. I watched all 9 videos by phpacademy, and I'm looking through the video to get a better idea of what things do.

Comment: 10 videos about Java by someone calling himself "phpacademy" is not very promising. And he is saying that this is the first lesson where you use objects. Also not very promising. [The official tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) would be a better place to start, and again, I would prefer a good book.

Answer (score 0):

The first error is created by a missing package declaration. To fix this, you can either move the class to the default package (not recommended) or you can add a package declaration via

```
package x.y.z;
```

at the top of your class while x.y.z is your package name.

The second error is caused by the second closing brace after the while statement

```
while(running) {
System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
}
} // This brace shall not be here
```

The compiler interprets this brace as the closing off your main method and isn't accepting methods after this brace anymore.

However, there are some other mistakes:
- A semicolon after the while statement
- The private modifier before local variables declarations

Comment: That brace closes the `main` method, not the class.

Comment: While not recommended, using the default package is *legal*, and therefore the error cannot be because of a missing package declaration.

Comment: I think he forgot the package statement while NOT having the class in the default package (happens when you are copy-pasting your code)

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a package declaration. For example

   ```
   package game;
   ```

   Alternatively, move it to the default package.
2. Close your class by adding `}` at the appropriate place. At the very end is a good place to start.
3. Fix your `while (enemyHealth > 0); {` loop by removing the `;` and adding a `}` to close the loop.
4. Move the loop into the `main` method.
5. Move `System.out.println("\t#" + enemy + " attacked! #\n");` into the `main` method as well.
6. Fix the quotes in this line `System.out.println("\t" + enemy + "'s +" " + HP: + " " + enemyHealth);` This will work:

   ```
   System.out.println("\t" + enemy + "'s HP:" + enemyHealth);
   ```
7. Now the variables `enemy` and `enemyHealth` also need to be moved into the `main` method. Your IDE may suggest making them static. However, since `Random rand = new Random();` is instantiated within the main method, it doesn't make sense to make them static.

---

Now your program will run. As for whether or not it actually does what it's supposed to do, I can't answer that since you didn't tell us.

```
package game;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    private static final String[] enemies = null;
    private Scanner rand;
    private int maxEnemyHealth;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();

        String[] enemies = { "troll", "rat", "imp", "goblin" };
        int maxEnemyHealth = 80;
        int enemyAttackDamage = 20;
        int health = 100;
        int playerAttackDamage = 30;
        int numHealthPots = 3;
        // int numStamimaPots = 3 (add stamina potions later on)
        int healthPotionHeal = 20;
        int healthPotionDropChance = 40; // 40%

        boolean running = true;
        System.out.println("Welcome, Dungeon Explorer!");

        GAME: while (running) {
            System.out
                    .println("-----------------------------------------------------");
        }

        int enemyHealth = rand.nextInt(maxEnemyHealth);
        String enemy = enemies[rand.nextInt(enemies.length)];

        while (enemyHealth > 0) {
            System.out.println("HP:" + health);
            System.out.println("\t" + enemy + "'s HP:" + enemyHealth);
            System.out.println("\n\t What do you choose to do?");
            System.out.println("\t Attack ");
            System.out.println("\t Health Potion");
            System.out.println("\t Run!");

            String input = in.nextLine();
        }

        System.out.println("\t#" + enemy + " attacked! #\n");
    }




}
```